# Expression Blend 4 failing when tries to load Reactive assembly

Tags: c#, silverlight, blend

Maybe someone have same problem

When I try to set data context type of view to desired View Model. The error appears:

> Could not load the assembly System.Reactive.Windows.Threading because
>   the following errors occurred: Method 'Schedule in type
>   'System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler' from assembly
>   *System.Reactive.Windows.Threading, Version=1.0.10621.0, Culture=
>   neutral, RublicKeyToken=31b13856ad364e35' does not have an
>   implementation.

Any thoughts? I have looked at disassembled code, and the method has implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a file reference to System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll to your project.
I've had a similar error and that fixed it.